# How to use external configuration file as a resource bundle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, resourcebundle

I am trying to access external configuration files in which my command line are as follows:

```
java -jar myApp.jar --spring.config.name=myConfig --spring.config.location="file:///C:\\Desktop\\myConfigs\\"
```

Within my code, this `myConfig.properties` is accessed using `ResourceBundle.getBundle('myConfig')` and `.getString("tbl.person")`. And having removed the file before I generated the .jar file, whenever I executed the above code, I am getting following error:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name myConfig, locale en_SG
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceExcepton(Unknown Source)
```

Snippet of myConfig.properties file:

```
tbl.person=Person
tbl.address=Address
```

I have tried `System.getProperty()` but to no avail results.

Appreciate in advance for any replies.

P.S: One of the reason I am calling this config file externally is because in the event if I needed to add in more info, there is no need for me to re-generate the .jar file all over again

Comment: Spring Boot is perfectly capable of loading files outside the classpath, you don't need to shoehorn that in yoruself.

Comment: I would just use ```FileInputStream```  to load the config

Comment: Yes I am aware of spring able to ingest external files, however I keep hitting into issues of the ResourceBundle. Mind if I ask if there are any examples for it?